# How do I get a Doctrine DQL query to work with subqueries?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Am trying to get a DQL result of two related entities to work but haven't had any success. Entity Post has a one to many relations with Entity Comment and Entity Comment has a Many to one relation with Entity Post. The thing about those tables is that each must be accessed using a `greatest-n-per-group` query as shown in the query below. There are many comments for every post. Comments are identified by email address or phone number.

So, would like a Post entity result whose comments can be identified by either a specified email address or phone number located in a contact field in the comments table.

The sql is this

```
SELECT 
    p1 
    
FROM App\Entity\Post p1 
    LEFT JOIN App\Entity\Post p2 WITH 
        p1.uid=p2.uid AND 
        p1.unique_id<p2.unique_id 
        
    LEFT JOIN App\Entity\Comment m2 WITH 
        m1.post_id=p1.uid AND 
        m2.contact IN(':email',':phone') AND 
        m2.language=0 AND
        NOT exists(
            SELECT 1
                FROM App\Entity\Comment
                WHERE
                (post_id=m2.post_id) AND
                ((coalesce(starttime, 0)=coalesce(m2.starttime, 0)) or (coalesce(starttime, 0)<=now())) AND
                ((coalesce(endtime, 0)=coalesce(m2.endtime, 0)) or (coalesce(endtime, 0)>=now())) AND
                (uid>m2.uid)
            ) 
            
WHERE p1.deleted=0 AND p2.uid IS NULL
```

How can I get this query to work in DQL?

Comment: Is there a need for self join for comments too? for post it looks fine to pick post wtih higher `unique_id` but comments it looks over complicated to add a self join because you already have another subquery to filter out comments

Comment: And also this DQL looks fine just add a parameter from code for `NOW()`, are you getting any error?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for the help. It doesn't work as it is. I had to split it to first find `unique_id` then use it to search for the other records. Joins do work with doctrine. I thought I would improve efficiency by using a single query instead of two.